# MySQL: Match Only Exact Strings in a String from a Table of Key Strings

Tags: mysql, sql-like, exact-match

I'm trying to match words from a table to a string when only the exact word matches, I've only been able to get very loose match so far by using a `LIKE` statement and it matches most things but the issue is it also matches partial words which I'm trying to avoid.

#### There isn't always a leading or trailing space.

### SQL Query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`keys` SEPARATOR ',')
FROM `table_keys`
WHERE "We Have One Cardboard Train Wheel" LIKE CONCAT('%', `keys`, '%');
```

### `table_keys`

```
| keys      |
|-----------|
| Car       |
| Wheel     |
| Roof      |
```

Two matchs are returned which is `Car, Wheel` which is technically correct but I only want it to match if the whole word is present.

### Current Output

```
Car,Wheel
```

### Wanted Output

```
Wheel
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are Strings

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_keys (
>
>   `keys` VARCHAR(5)
>
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table_keys
>   ( `keys`)
> VALUES
>   ('Car'),
>   ( 'Wheel'),
>   ( 'Roof');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`keys` SEPARATOR ',') AS "keys"
> FROM `table_keys`
> WHERE "We Have One Cardboard Train Wheel"  
> regexp CONCAT('(^|[[:space:]])',`keys`,'([[:space:]]|$)')
> ```
>
> ```
> | keys  |
> | :---- |
> | Wheel |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4c738bfb6e07ff52e6a92a3a169e81a)*

Comment: it's a step in the right direction be I can't guarantee there will always be a leading or trailing space.

Comment: This seems to work, `REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]' , keys , '[[:>:]]')`.